# Add NetBeans CRUD auto-code to existing project

Tags: java, netbeans, crud, wizard

I have a project in Java that is pretty much done, except I need to make just a couple of more CRUD frames. Now the easiest way to do this would be through the NetBeans auto-code with a couple of clicks. I know how to do this when NetBeans gives me that option WHEN I MAKE A NEW PROJECT, but I don't know how to add CRUD frames to an existing one.

So, is there a way to add CRUD frames to an existing project in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

[image]

1. Start New File wizard, either by right clicking on the package node or File menu.
2. Choose "Swing GUI Forms" category and "Master/Detail sample Form" File type from the file types list
3. Now you will be following the same CRUD form creation wizard

with regards
Tushar Joshi, Nagpur